# Order of callback events in keycloak javascript adapter

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-javascript

The supported callbacks for keycloak javascript adapter are listed here: [Keycloak Docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#callback-events). Currently, my code relies on the assumption that, if the user is authenticated, then `onAuthSuccesss` is always triggered before `onReady`. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Just had a similar question and just logged all the events and tried a few flows. From that it looks like that assumption holds true.